# Getting ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE error laravel5 localhost

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, laravel-5, localhost

I'm getting stuck when I launch my **laravel 5** project on localhost on **Google Chrome**.
I'm using the bootstrap admin panel from this repo: https://github.com/start-laravel/sb-admin-laravel-5

I installed al the needs, like **npm**, **bower** and **gulp**.
I cleared cache and then I run `php artisan serve`

When I navigate to `localhost:8000` the page loads fine, but the styles.css and the frontend.js will not be loaded.

I'm getting the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/assets/stylesheets/styles.css net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE 
GET http://localhost:8000/assets/scripts/frontend.js net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
GET http://localhost:8000/favicon.ico net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

I've tried the following things:

- Cleared cache laravel
- Cleared cache browser
- Disabled chrome extensions
- Going incognito
- Created new files, copied the css and js and put it in the new file
- Searched the whole internet for a solution, which I haven't found..

**My Code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("assets/stylesheets/styles.css") }}" />
<script src="{{ asset("assets/scripts/frontend.js") }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**But**

When I run my project using XAMPP (the url then is: *http://localhost/website-monitor/public*/) it all works fine.. :/ the only thing is, i'm running the site just to going to the path and not using artisan..

If anyone have the solution, please let me now, i've spilled my whole day on this annoying bug

Comment: I've fixed the problem. This bootstrap admin panel is not compatible with PHP 7.0, PHP 5.6 works fine!

Answer (score 12):

Instead of `php artisan serve` try using `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` in your project's home directory. Works like a charm for me!

Comment: can you explain this? +1 it helped me

Comment: It just sets the native, php server at -S address with the starting point (root) at -t .
It helps when dealing with the absolute paths better than the artisan server does.